# how to comment crontab entries that match word and then restore to original

Tags: sed

I have this in crontab:

```
#### this is AAA
0 0,8 * * * ${HOME}/script.sh AAA
##### this is BBB
0 0,8 * * * ${HOME}/script.sh BBB
```

I have a script that need to comment out BBB job at beginning and once finish put crontab as it was originally
at beginning of script need to have crontab like this:

```
#### this is AAA
0 0,8 * * * ${HOME}/script.sh AAA
##### this is BBB
#0 0,8 * * * ${HOME}/script.sh BBB
```

once script ends restore crontab to this:

```
#### this is AAA
0 0,8 * * * ${HOME}/script.sh AAA
##### this is BBB
0 0,8 * * * ${HOME}/script.sh BBB
```

I was able to copy crontab to a file and then modifying file with sed (any idea how to do this in one line?)

```
crontab -l > crontab.bak
sed -i 's/^[^#]*BBB/#&/' crontab.bak
```

and how to remove the comment?
thanks!

```
crontab -l > crontab.bak
 sed -i 's/^[^#]*BBB/#&/' crontab.bak
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're really trying to do. Your sed command isn't modifying the system crontab file, it's just modifying the copy you made of it by running `ctontab -l` so when you say you need to "put crontab as it was originally" - the system crontab file is already what it was originally, it hasn't changed.

Comment: correct, it hasn't changed, because I do not know how to remove the comments from backup file to put it back as it was originally.

Comment: But why do you need to remove the comments from the backup file? Just delete it when you're done with it and keep using the system one.

Comment: ahh sorry for confusion, after I created a .bak file with file commeted I replaced crontab with that one, now crontab has the same as crontab.bak, now I need to remove # from BBB line to put it as it was before
Before:
#### this is AAA
0 0,8 * * * ${HOME}/script.sh AAA
##### this is BBB
0 0,8 * * * ${HOME}/script.sh BBB
crontab.bak -> crontab
#### this is AAA
0 0,8 * * * ${HOME}/script.sh AAA
##### this is BBB
#0 0,8 * * * ${HOME}/script.sh BBB -> need to remove # from this line
and created crontab again (restore it as it was originally)

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`, if the comment is present, this will remove it (and vice versa) and load the file back to your crontab.

```
$ sed -E '/BBB$/{n;/^#/{s///;q};/^#/!{s/^/#/;q}};' > crontab.bak <(crontab -l) ; crontab crontab.bak
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer follows on from @HatLess's one. Using a single pipeline without a temp file:

```bash
crontab -l | sed ... | crontab -
```

You might want a backup in case things go wrong though:

```bash
crontab -l | tee crontab.bak | sed ... | crontab -
```

Comment: tanks works fine, now do you know how to remove comments to make it back as it was before?
#### this is AAA
0 0,8 * * * ${HOME}/script.sh AAA
##### this is BBB
#0 0,8 * * * ${HOME}/script.sh BBB -> this is that I have now after run
crontab -l | sed ... | crontab -
now I need to remove # from this #0 0,8 * * * ${HOME}/script.sh BBB

Comment: `sed -E 's/^#+(.*script.sh BBB.*)/\1/'`

Comment: thanks, and now how to remove the # from BBB line to restore it to original?